# How come the context of my form.py is not showing up?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-csrf

I have had the same problem for quite some time and have been trying different solutions but nothing is working. I have seen different examples here on the website, but most of them are addressing older versions of Django. I have tried such solutions, but nothing is workin.
The problem is as addressed by the title,

" A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext. "

I have tried to add `RequestContext(request)` to my code instead of writing `{'form': 'form'}` but it didn't work out.
I have tried to use `HttpResponse()` instead of `render_to_response` in my urls' views, but didn't work out as well.

This is the for my original views.py before I alter anything!

```
            def ask_page_view(request):
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = Ask_Page_Form(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
                else:
                    form = Ask_Page_Form()
                return render(request, "ask.html",  {'form': form })
```

This is the views.py when I have added the `RequestContext()`

```
        def ask_page_view(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = Ask_Page_Form(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    pass
                else:
                    form = Ask_Page_Form()
                return renderto('ask.html', context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This is the forms.py that I am using:

```
        from django import forms

        class Ask_Page_Form(forms.Form):
            name = forms.CharField(
                max_length=30,
                widget=forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                                'placeholder': 'Write your name here',
                                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                                'label': 'Student Name'
                            }
            ))
            email = forms.EmailField(
                max_length=254,
                widget=forms.EmailInput(
                        attrs={
                                'placeholder': 'Write your Email here',
                                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                                'label': 'Email'
                            }
            ))
            subject = forms.CharField(
                max_length=50,
                widget = forms.TextInput(
                        attrs={
                                'placeholder': 'Write your Question or Related Subject here',
                                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                                'label': 'Subject'
                            }
            ))

            message = forms.CharField(
                max_length=2000,
                widget=forms.Textarea(
                        attrs={
                                'placeholder': 'Write your message here',
                                'class': 'ask-page-input',
                                'label': 'Message'
                            }
            ))


            source = forms.CharField(       # A hidden input for internal use
                max_length=50,              # tell from which page the user sent the message
                widget=forms.HiddenInput()
            )

            def clean(self):
                cleaned_data = super(Ask_Page_Form, self).clean()
                name = cleaned_data.get('name')
                email = cleaned_data.get('email')
                subject = cleaned_data.get('subject')
                message = cleaned_data.get('message')
                if not name and not email and not subject and not message:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('You have to write something!')
```

This is the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Physics Quizzes Ask</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have four input fields where the user can type whatever question that he/ she thinks about and then send it with a submit button to the admin's email. But the fields are not showing up and only the button does.
Thank you :)

Comment: can you show your html where you have posted the form

Comment: try this before render `args = {} args.update(csrf(request)) args['form'] = form` and then `return return render(request, "ask.html", args)` csrf is defined in `from django.template.context_processors import csrf` so don't forget to import it.

Comment: Maybe are you missing `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in `settings.MIDDLEWARE` ?

Comment: I have the CSRF in the Settings, and I have posted the HTML code. And going to try @Ahtisham method in a minute.

Comment: before `form` tag type `<a href="/your_app_name/ask_page_view">create form</a>` and click on it... how do you think it will get called on its own ? you need to first call the view. then it will display the form for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate the form you need to call the view:

html:

```
<a href="/your_app_name/ask_page_view">create form</a> 
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

your_app's urls.py:

```
url(r'ask_page_view/$', views.ask_page_view),
```

view.py:

```
from django.template.context_processors import csrf

def ask_page_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Ask_Page_Form(request.POST) 
       if form.is_valid(): # here you validate the created form
          pass  # does nothing, just trigger the validation
       else:
          form = Ask_Page_Form() # here you create a new form          

       args = {}
       args.update(csrf(request))
       args['form'] = form
    return render(request, "ask.html", args)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this time, I am receiving this: `args = { } IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`
And I have already called the page using `path('ask/', views.ask, name = 'ask_page')` Or do you want me to call the function inside of the views?

Comment: I don't have any probelm with the form, but it is not showing up because I am calling it in a wrong way probably. I am not sure how doing it, I want the form to be on `ask.html` not click on a link and go to the form. And this is what I am doing.
`path('ask/', views.ask, name = 'ask_page'),`
This is the HTML:
`    <form action="ask.html" method="POST">`

Comment: what is the name of the view ? that you are calling ?

Comment: The name of the function in my `views.py` is `ask_page_view` but I would like the form to be on the ask.html file/ page.